# SF Data Entry Event transfers wrong Account:ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, servicecloud, entry-criteria

We use Service Cloud as DOR. Here we use Leads just for NL subscribers. Customers are Accounts. For the Double Opt-In process we have two boolean fields.

Email_Optin
Email_Optin_confirmed

Email_Optin = True triggers the DOI Journey in the Marketing Cloud via SF Data Entry Event. The Account:Id is transferred with the DOI Confirmation Link

```
%%[
Var @rows, @row, @Id, @email
Set @email = AttributeValue('Account:PersonContact:Email')
Set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'Id', 'PersonEmail', '=', @email)
Set @row = row(@rows, 1)
Set @id =field(@row,'Id')
]%%
```

and

`%%=Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/15...5/?sfid=',@id, '&email=', @email )=%%`

In a Use Case where two Persons use the same Email Address, for example info@domain.com, the following happens.

1. Person A is an old customer and has not subscribed to NL
2. Person B is a customer since one week and has not subscribed to NL
3. Both use the same Email info@domain.com
4. Person A subscribes to the NL
5. The Account:Id which is transferred to my DOI Journey is always the Id of Person B, which is wrong

Is it ever happen to someone or does anyone have experience on that?

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do a lookup in CRM to get the Accoun:Id, if your entry event is based on the CRM Account object. Just ensure you include these fields in your Event Fields when you set up the entry event.

[image]

With this type of event data, setting up your variables would look like this...

```
%%[
Set @email = AttributeValue('Account:PersonContact:Email')
Set @id = AttributeValue('Account:Id')
]%%
```

Finally, you'll run into issues with tracking your links with a URL like you have there. Besides needing to place it in a RedirectTo, you'd generate thousands of tracked links. You should do something like the following in your HTML:

```
<a href="https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/15...5/?sfid=%%=v(@id)=%%&email=%%=v(@email)=%%" alias="Double OptIn Link">Confirm Sign Up</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This resolves the other problem also. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear you're sorted :)

Comment: You can mark as answered, if this resolves you question.